# React Hooks: Referencing data that is stored inside context from inside useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a large JSON blob stored inside my Context that I can then make references to using jsonpath (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath)

How would I go about being able to access the context from inside useEffect() without having to add my context variable as a dependency (the context is updated at other places in the application)?

```
export default function JsonRpc({ task, dispatch }) {
  const { data } = useContext(DataContext);
  const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    task.keys.forEach(key => {
      let val = jp.query(data, key.key)[0];
      jp.value(task.payload, key.result_key, val);
    });
    let newPayload = {
      jsonrpc: "2.0",
      method: "call",
      params: task.payload,
      id: "1"
    };

    const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_WF_SERVER;
    let params = {};
    if (task.method === "GET") {
      params = newPayload;
    }
    const domain_params =
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("domain_params")) || [];
    domain_params.forEach(e => {
      if (e.domain === domain) {
        params[e.param] = e.value;
      }
    });
    setFetchData({ ...task, payload: newPayload, params: params });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [task]);

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure because there's only a part of your code, but.. Shouldn't you already be able to access `data` from inside the `useEffect`? What's your problem, again?

Comment: @Jolly yes i can access data from inside useEffect() but i don't want to add `data` as a dependency as it is updated in other components which would cause the effect to run again calling `setFetchData()` which would trigger an unwanted api call.

Comment: Ok so.. You need the `useEffect` to be run any time `task` variable changes, BUT you also need `data` to be up-to-date when that happen, inside the `useEffect`, am I right? Moreover, you **DO NOT** want `data` to be placed in the dependencies array. Am I correct?

Comment: @Jolly yes that is correct, once `setFetchData()` is called that triggers another effect which makes an axios call, the result of that then updates the `data` variable which in turn causes this effect to re-trigger resulting in a infinite loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your reply @Jolly! I found a work around:

I moved the data lookup to a state initial calculation:

```
const [fetchData] = useState(processFetchData(task, data));
```

then im just making sure i clear the component after the axios call has been made by executing a complete function passed to the component from its parent.

This works for now, but if you have any other suggestions id love to hear them!

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna need to post an answer because of code, but I'm not 100% sure about what you need, so I'll build a correct answer with your feedback :)

So, my first idea is: can't you split your effects in two `React.useEffect`? Something like this:

```
export default function JsonRpc({ task, dispatch }) {
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    ...
    setFetchData(...);
  }, [task]);


  useEffect(() => {
    ...
  }, [data]);

   .. 
}
```

Now, if my understanding are correct, this is an example of events timeline:

1. Due to the update on `task` you will trigger the first `useEffect`, which can `setFetchData()`;
2. Due to the update on `fetchData`, and AXIOS call is made, which updates `data` (property in the context);
3. At this, you enter the second `useEffect`, where you have the updated `data`, but **NO** call to `setFetchData()`, thus no loop;

Then, if you wanted (but couldn't) put `data` in the dependencies array of your `useEffect`, I can imagine the two `useEffect` I wrote have some shared code: you can write a common method called by both `useEffect`s, **BUT** it's important that the `setFetchData()` call is outside this common method.

Let me know if you need more elaboration.